# Git untracked file in new feature branch

Tags: git, commit, git-untracked

I was working on a feature branch locally, and added a new folder with a file in it. I then committed these new files along with my other changes and pushed to a remote server.

I am now working on a different feature branch from master; however the folder/file I added from the previous feature branch is showing in 'git status' as untracked and when I try to commit locally from my new feature branch, the folder stages itself for commit. I have tried to remove the folder using git clean -fd, but it then reappears when I am committing!

How do I deal with this untracked folder?

Comment: What command are you using to commit ? `git commit -a` ?

Answer (score 0):

If the file is committed when running `git commit`, it somehow got staged before.

To remove it from the staging area, run :

```
git reset folder/file
```

You should not see it anymore in your next

```
git commit
```

If it is not tracked and still present on your disk, and you *know* you want to delete it, just remove it with a regular `rm`.